# Disable jQuery SnapPoint for tablet/mobile devices

Tags: destroy, enquire.js

I'm a bit stumped on this one.

How would I go about turning off the following code for mobile/tablets (<768px) and turning it on for desktop (>786px)?

Github:
https://github.com/robspangler/jquery-snappoint

Demo:
http://robspangler.com/git/jquery-snappoint/demo/demo.html

A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found the enquire.js (Media Queries for Javascript)... Looks like I would need to add a destroy function to the query-snappoint function... Again, any insights would be helpful... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you're basically asking for is a way to undo whatever was done by the plugin in question. Which translates to this in enquire:

```
enquire.register("(min-width:768px)", {
    match : function() {
        //apply the plugin
    },
    unmatch : function() {
        //undo whatever the plugin did
    }
}, true);
```

The `true` at the end is telling enquire to always consider this a match for incapable browsers. That way old IE etc will always get the desktop version, while everyone else behaves correctly. See the "mobile-first" section here: http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/#delving-deeper for more info

So, looking at that plugin it doesn't provide an API to turn off/undo it's behaviour (a common theme with jQuery plugins). Thankfully though, it seems the only thing it does is attach a listener for window scroll events. So you should just be able to do this:

```
enquire.register("(min-width:768px)", {
    match : function() {
        $(".whatever").snapPoint();
    },
    unmatch : function() {
        $(window).off("resize");
    }
}, true);
```

Note: the plugin in question doesn't namespace the event handler it attaches, so we're forced to be a bit heavy handed and turn off *all resize event handlers*. This ultimately means what we're doing here could affect other plugin's behaviour.

If for some reason what I've suggested doesn't work (and in light of the note above), you should consider raising an issue with the plugin author to:

1. provide a mechanism to undo it's behaviour
2. namespace event handlers so they can be removed without affecting other handlers.

Hope that helps.